# makefile on windows with wildcard in command to javac

Tags: java, makefile

I'm writing a makefile for a partially java project. I'm porting this to Windows, so I'm adapting a makefile which is being invoked with mingw. Anyways, the problem I've run into is that I want to invoke

```
javac *.java
```

When running the makefile I get

```
javac *.java
javac: file not found: *.java
```

But if I invoke it directly in the command prompt, I get the expected wildcard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you run "javac *.java" in a folder which has 
no java files, this is what you get.

So it seems your make file is not in the 
same folder as your *.java files.